# Shared iAd banner for UITabBarController based app using XCode 4 with storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

[Storyboard iAd Tab Bar Controller sample project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43437305/TabTest.zip)

1: Download sample project for Xcode 4.2

2: Make the banner visible above the Tab Bar from every view

3: post answer

4: recieve bounty

5: make other people happy, I will tutorialize it. No place existing tutorial for this important step atm.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple actually. Just create a new banner view controller for each tab that will be the parent view controller for each tab in your storyboard. Then drag in a *Container View* object into each banner view controller and embed your child view controllers in each banner view controller.

Finally in BannerViewController.m replace the custom init method a method to override `initWithCoder:` where you will add the banner view controller to the banner manager. Also implement `prepareForSegue:` where you can set the `_contentController` to the segue's destination view controller.

My [blog post](http://stevemoser.org/blog/2013/04/24/how-to-create-a-shared-iad-banner-in-a-tabbed-application-with-storyboards/) goes into a lot more detail and links to an example project.

Answer (score 0):

Before we try anything drastic, try putting this code at the bottom of your `appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, just before your `return YES;` call:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it made nothing different I think. Isn't that kind of the same as this line: UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

Comment: You keep changing your question text. If you want someone to code this for you I suggest you post a project on freelancer.com or elance.com. Good luck :)

Comment: Yeah I changed it to a general sample so it will be easier and more general so others can use this in a without going through my personal codes to find what they want. Thanks for the advice, will do that if Apple's support mail doesn't make me wiser on the subject!