# Displaying AdMob banner without delay in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads, banner

According to https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start I add AdMob banner to my View Controller with code

```
 self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ID_GOES_HERE";
 self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
 [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

what actually works well, however every time I need to wait 1/2 seconds until banner appears. Can I for example initialize somehow all banners which I want to use in my app in AppDelegate, loading screen or somewhere else, save them in sharedManager and then just to display in View Controllers without delay, at the same time as other elements of UI?

Comment: What you're looking for is a shared banner. Here's an example implementing with iAd for Swift (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514758/swift-iad-more-than-10-instances-of-adbannerview-warning-and-cgaffinetransform/28639200#28639200). Creating only one banner initially and then utilizing it effectively throughout your app is the best practice.