# Simultaneous iAD's results in only one getting served

Tags: objective-c, admob, iad, ios-app-group

I seem to have a peculiar problem, which is as follows. I have two views in an iOS app 1) TableViewController View as a table and a click on a particular row of the table would land me in new UIView. I am using iAd to serve banner ads on those two views.

Now the problem is : iAd is not serving ads on the second view after it had served on the landing table view. But if I disable the ads on the first view i.e table view controller I can see the ads being served on the second page i.e UIview.

I have also checked these against admob and found that above doesn't seem to happen with them.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What you want to do is create a Shared iAd Banner. This is an ad banner you create once and use across your entire app. Requesting ads on each new view in your app is frowned upon by iAd resulting in low fill rates. Here's a link to a similar question implementing a Shared iAd Banner using Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion looks a better way ahead. It'd be great if you can share an example working code in objective - C .