# How do I add iAd banner on top of TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, iad, adbannerview

So I tried to add iAd in appdelegate. and I get this error

> ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController

I want to show the banner on all views. I tried on how to add shared iAd but what it does is, it shows the banner under the tableview.

Is there anyway to show the iAd banner on top of all the viewcontrollers?

Comment: show some relative code?

Comment: @Yuchen well i need the code/way actually, Tried searching the internet I dont really see anything related to this.

Comment: Here's an example of how to implement a Shared Banner in Swift.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514758/swift-iad-more-than-10-instances-of-adbannerview-warning-and-cgaffinetransform/28639200#28639200

Use the shared banner you have implemented and use `bringSubviewToFront` when the new view controller finishes loading. For example, `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];`.

If you could include a screenshot and some code of what you have implemented so far that would help immensely.