# Shared iAd on Tabbed Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

New to iOS development and I have a tabbed app with 4 tabs. I have an iAd showing on one tab and I don't want to regurgetate the code on every view controller and I know this is not the correct way to implement anyway. I have looked at the Apple code here and I'm struggling to be honest.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

I have included the BannerViewController.m and BannerViewController.h in my application but I'm not fully sure how to get it to run the ad on each view controller.

Yours confused

JKX

Comment: add the banner to UIWindow

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you elaborate slightly. where do I add it to UI window?

Comment: currently you might be adding the banner view by writing the code self.view addSubview I guess..... If you add anything on UIWindow which has a reference made in appdelegate then that view will appear forever and you dont have to rewrite any code in various viewcontrollers separately.

Comment: you can take reference of UIWindow in any of the view controllers or even in appDelegate and add the banner to UIWindow.

Comment: I had self.view addSubview what is the method for UIWindow

Comment: i have just posted in detail

Comment: JKX,  I wrote a tutorial on iAd implementation and use this for one of my apps with a tab bar. You might want to check it out. http://thefizixgroup.blogspot.com/p/iad-implementation_6.html?m=1

Comment: @Douglas thank you, although not the perfect answer for the question it did put me on the right track to achieving my goal!

Comment: Glad it got you going in the right direction!!

Comment: Here's an example of a Shared Banner implemented in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547 It's easily translated to Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab a reference of UIWindow in any of your ViewController Class
Go to .m of your ViewController

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
  //make object of AppDelegate
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

Now in your viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear grab the reference of window.

```
appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.window addSubview:yourBannerView];
```

Comment: Doesn't work ..throws following error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController'

Comment: just do one thing make any simple UIView and add it to the window just like the above code and see whether that uiview is available on all view controllers

Comment: I'm trying to implement the shared ad using the BannerViewController.m and BannerViewController.h, have you any answer for the question as described above?