# iAd in my app doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I added iAd banner in my app, and the code is like this:

```
@IBOutlet var adBannerview: ADBannerView?
```

and codes that in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerview?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerview?.hidden = true
```

then:

```
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {


    }
   func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.adBannerview?.hidden = false


    }
   func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {


    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication: Bool) -> Bool {

        return true

    }

   func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError: NSError!) {
    self.adBannerview?.hidden = true


    }



}
```

Now, my app is sale on app store, I downloaded that, but when I open it, found there's no ads on the bottom, is that something wrong with my code? But when I run the app on simulator, it says "Connected to iAd".
Appreciate if you help!

Comment: Might be of interest to note that iAds don't always appear.

Comment: When i ran that on simulator, I got an error: Ad was unloaded from this banner, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually attempting to implement two iAd `ADBannerView`'s here. You can use either the `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, which you have in your `viewDidLoad` function, and remove your other iAd code (`@IBOutlet var adBannerview: ADBannerView?`, `self.adBannerview?.delegate = self`, `self.adBannerview?.hidden = true`). `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` will create an iAd banner for you and manage itself whether it receives an ad from iAd or not. This is the no hassle way of implementing iAd banners into your application but doesn't allow for much control.

Alternatively, you could remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and implement the iAd `ADBannerView` yourself. This allows for more control but does require more than just one line of code to get it up and running, but it is still very simple to implement. You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) for some guidance if you choose to go this route.

Also, you have all of your `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods inside your view controllers `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function. They need to be placed outside of this and any other function.

Answer (score 0):

It often takes a week or more for live ads to start appearing. There is a separate review process from Apple's ad team that can take up to 10 business days in the worst case.