# iAds 10 Instances

Tags: objective-c, iad

I have a app that has about 14 pages.The navigation bar and iAds location stays the same but only the middle content changes. When I switch through my pages I get a message that there are 10 instances of iAdBanner. Is there a way I can make the iAD lock onto the main screen so that when I switch onto next screen the iAd will remain at the bottom for the rest of the screens without it refreshing each time (aka only have 1 iAd in multiple views)?

Currently here is my iAd Code

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

Comment: I made a post about that if you want to check it out. http://thefizixgroup.blogspot.com/p/iad-implementation_6.html?m=1  It allows only one instance of the iAd banner to be shared on all VC's. Try it out.

Comment: What you're looking for is a Shared Banner http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547