# Implement a single iAd banner across entire multi page app using Swift

Tags: swift, iad

Does anyone know how to implement a single iAd banner that sits at the top level of your app so that every view controller that is displayed contains the same instance of the single iAd banner?

I had an implementation a few years ago in Obj-C but cannot find an equivalent in Swift.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) should get you started. Just move the delegate methods to your `AppDelgate.swift`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Was ideally looking for an iad viewcontroller that I could add as the entrance view to my app - which all other views (including my tabbarcontrollers and navigationcontrollers can then sit inside).  Had something like this for objc but cant find anything in swift.

Answer (score 0):

As the user above me said what you are looking for is a shared banner ad. You don't need to move the delegates to app delegate.swift, you just need to add the properties there. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html

I made an ad helper for swift, why don't you check it out.
https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-iAds-and-AdMob-Helper