# How to set iAd Delegate to new View Controller

Tags: delegates, swift2, iad, viewcontroller, xcode7

I am developing an application using Xcode 7 and Swift 2. I recently discovered an error in my code. In the debugger log (I think that is what it is called) , it printed this:

```
[AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=7, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
```

I did some research and found out that I needed this code:

```
iAdBannerView.delegate = self
```

In my `viewDidLoad` method. I tried it, and I no longer recieved the error. However, I have two viewControllers. Both contain iAds. In the original view controller, ViewController.swift, the code workds. In the view controller that I later added, AboutViewContoller, I get this error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'AboutViewController' to a value of type 'ADBannerViewDelegate?"
```

Could someone please show me my error in my code?

Comment: Does your `AboutViewController` adopt the `ADBannerViewDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Good point. I don't think It did adapt it. How should I check/ fix it?

Comment: You would have to adjust the declaration of the class to something like `class AboutViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate`

Comment: You should be using a shared banner if you're going to be displaying your `ADBannerView` on multiple views: [Shared iAd Banner in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier, I had:

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController {
```

I forgot the `ADBannerViewDelegate`. The correct code is:

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
```

Thanks to [Charles A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2666110/charles-a) and [Daniel Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108547/daniel-storm) for helping out!