# No ad to show on real device but working on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I am trying to create and load interstitial ads however the problem is that on the real device I am always getting error

> Request Error: No ad to show.

But on the simulator, it works! What could be the problem? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697848/3848797) answer. Everything works on simulator but not on real device.

If I use the test `adUnitID` then it works on real device also. But why the real `adUnitID` is causing problems on real device but not on the simulator?

Sometimes they are showing sometimes not. Is there some limit that one person can have like 10 ads?

Comment: there is no limit unless you cap it while configuring the adunit... 1.There might be limited inventory in country you are serving the advertisements 2.Usually it takes a day to start seeing prod live, is app live for more than a day? 3. Try changing adunitid and see if it generates the advertisements

Comment: @AmodGokhale Sorry for the late answer. The thing is that the application have been on the app store pretty much a year. Now they suddenlty stopped working. I tried creating new ads but that is not the case.