# iOS/Swift: more than 10 instances of ADBannerView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, adbannerview

I am getting this warning after 10 screenviews.

> More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently
>   exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer
>   as a result. This message is printed only once.

I have implemented `AdBannerView` through InterfaceBuilder. I am **not** explicitely creating an ADBannerView programmatically each time the view is loaded.

I am just referencing the `AdBannerView` as an @IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var iAdsBanner: ADBannerView!
```

and hiding/showing it by changing its position, as suggested by Apple documentation.

Why am I getting this kind of error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why are your making an outlet for bannerView. After iOS 7 things have been changed. If you want iAds  then all you need to do is add the `iAdsFramework`, import the framework in  your `UIViewController`  and in your `viewDidLoad()` write the following code

```
 self.canDisplayBannerAds = true;
```

It will start displaying ads.

**UPDATE**
Forget the `canDisplayBannerAds` thing as your requirement is different. Just create a single instance for banner View in your `AppDelegate` and in your view controller get that instance , set frames and add it as subview and don't forget to remove it when your controller disappears.check this link you will get the idea. [stackoverflow.com/questions/28514758/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514758/%E2%80%A6)

Comment: it's because i need to place the banner in a certain position, following specific constraints

Comment: Alright, then you should properly  remove your bannerView  in your controller's viewDidDisappear if you are creating instance for every screen. Or  make only one  instance of  adBannerView  like in AppDelegate  and add/remove it on your controller's view

Comment: I have a banner in 2 different view controllers. I believe I am not creating an instance everytime, as I just added the banners using InterfaceBuilder, referencing them in the code as an outlet. If I create just one instance in the AppDelegate, how would I be able to position them in the Interface Builder?

Comment: but they are active and displaying ads though your controller is not visible.  you will need to add them programmatically. like subview and you need to define frames for  your banner view or you can also add it as subview on window.

Comment: I am confused now. If I understand correctly, you are saying I should not add them using InterfaceBuilder. But how should I create them, using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` or creating the instance in the AppDelegate? In case I create the instance in the AppDelegate, should I create two different istances (1 for each view controller) or just one? and should I still hide them using `viewDidDisappear`?

Comment: don't be confused :). Forget the  canDisplayBannerAds thing as your requirement is different. Just create a single instance for banner View in your AppDelegate  and  in your view controller get that instance , set frames and add it as subview and don't forget to remove it when your controller disappears.check this link you will get the idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514758/swift-iad-more-than-10-instances-of-adbannerview-warning-and-cgaffinetransform

Comment: Ok thanks! Can you confirm if it's enough to create just 1 instance, or should I create two different instances, one for each of the two view controllers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98060/discussion-between-muneeba-and-daniele-b).