# Sizing iAd Banner Views

Tags: ios, iad

This seems like it should be simple, but the documentation is very unclear. In the [introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ADBannerView) of the `ADBannerView` class, Apple says this:

> A banner view must always use one of the standard sizes defined in
>   Content Size Identifiers. This is to ensure that the advertisement is
>   drawn correctly. You configure the banner view’s
>   `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers` property with the set of possible sizes
>   your view is allowed to use in your application. To change the size of
>   the banner view, do not set the bounds directly; instead set the
>   `currentContentSizeIdentifier` property to one of the size identifiers
>   included in that set. You can retrieve the actual dimensions that a
>   particular identifier equates to on a specific device by calling the
>   `sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:` class method.

However, these methods are all marked in the documentation as deprecated since iOS 6:

> **Deprecation Statement:** Banner views no longer use content size
>   identifiers. See Content Size Identifiers for details.

If you go to ["Content Size Identifiers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Content_Size_Identifiers), nothing can be found except the documentation for these constants, all marked as depricated since iOS 6. The rest of the documentation doesn't seem to be any help either.

If these methods are deprecated, and nothing seems to have taken their place, how are you supposed to resize and get the size of iAd banners?

Comment: Why don't you use Autolyaout ? (like in this example : http://concentricsky.com/blog/2014/sep/implement-iad-and-let-layout-constraints-do-lifting)

Comment: @Vinzzz: I just started a long comment to you about the reasons I can't (all sorts of stuff with ad animations and real-time can't-be-lost touch interactions), but you just gave me an idea. I'll leave the question in case anybody does need this information though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to set the `ADBannerView`'s size. Your `ADBannerView` will know which device it is on and set the dimensions of itself correctly. All you need to do is set the `ADBannerView`'s position. Check [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) for an example.

If you're using Auto Layout and wanted the `ADBannerView` to be at the bottom of the screen then pin it to the bottom of the screen with `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide` and align it to `Align Center X to: Superview`. Be sure you **do not** set any height, width, trailing, or leading constraints

Comment: And just ignore Xcode screaming about missing constraints?

Comment: @Linuxios simply put, yes. Give it a try and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I still have no idea about resizing, but I figured out initial sizing.

Since iOS 6, `ADBannerView`s have an [`adType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ADBannerView/adType) property. This property can be either `ADAdTypeBanner` or `ADAdTypeMediumRectangle`. The documentation gives the sizes for both kinds:
The banner height varies with device type and orientation as follows:

```
UI Idiom and Orientation   | Ad Height
--------------------------------------
phone, portrait            | 50 points
phone, landscape           | 32 points
pad, portrait or landscape | 66 points
```

As for resizing, I can only assume that the banner view automatically takes the width of the screen by observing orientation change notifications.