# Can you preload admob DFPBannerView on iOS

Tags: ios, admob, adbannerview

Can you preload admob DFPRequest on iOS?  I know you can for interstitials, but was wondering about DFPBannerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `GADBannerView` and one request in`applicationDidFinishLaunching`, listen to the `GADBannerView`'s delegate method to know when it's loaded, and then present it on any view you desire. `applicationDidFinishLaunching` would be the earliest you could make your request. Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) using an `ADBannerView` and Swift. The implementation would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it for banners. Once you call `LoadAd()` for a banner ad unit, your banner ad starts loading and refreshes after a set interval (what you've set on the dashboard, or the default), if any.

There is no way to preload admob banner ads like interstitial.