# ADBannerView shows up as white

Tags: ios, swift, iad, adbannerview

I am trying to implement a shared `ADBannerView`, which is kept in the App Delegate.

Is there any specific reason why the first time the banner loads in a View Controller it shows up as white?

Then in the following loads for that View Controller, the light-blue iAd banner gets loaded correctly.

Comment: By the way, [*"the iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016"*](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a).

Comment: @Pang thanks so much for this news! I didn't know about! So, what do you sugggest to use? AdMob for iOS?

Comment: You're probably not hiding your `ADBannerView` when you initially create it. It takes time for the ad to load. Look at [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) of a shared iAd banner.

Comment: @DanielStorm thanks for replying. However I have decided to stop using Apple's iAd, as it's going to be discontinued soon. I am going to use AdMob.