# How to request AdMob Interstitial before transition to display the ads immediatelly

Tags: ios, admob

I've been using AdMob integration (interstitial ads) in my project.

My project has the following structure:
-Main Screen
-Choose Level
-Play Screen

Is there anyway to request the interstitial ads in the Main Screen, and once the user enters the category or play screen the interstitial ads would be available to show?

Currently the example provided by AdMob only shows code for a single page, which is to load and cache in the page itself. I would like to create an object or singleton in my App Delegate which would persist across all my View Controllers.

Comment: Create and request the interstitial in your App Delegate. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) using an `ADBannerView`. The implementation would be the same.