# How to create a shared Admob banner for multiple views?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gadbannerview

I am buildung my very first application with Admob banners in Xcode.
My apps uses multiple `UIViews` connect via `NavigationController` and currently I am requesting a new ad for every `UIView`.

That is what I already got for every `UIViewController`:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-281379xxxxx/64134xxxxx"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    }
}
```

How can I implement a "*shared*" banner for all views which gets managed from a separate `class` or by the `AppDelegate`. (All of my views got an `GADBannerView` at the bottom already.)

I never really worked with delegate methods before, because coding is just hobby from me and I am learning like: Try & Error. But at this point my skills aren't good enough to realize this.

I would appreciate any kind of help :-). Thank you!

Comment: Here's an example of a shared iAd banner. It's the same concept. Just replace the `ADBannerView` code with your `GADBannerView` code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547

Comment: Sorry, this didn't helped me. iAd needs to be handled different.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you find the way?

Comment: Also wondering if you found a way. I'm checking around now and not finding anything.